# flutter video how can i stretch becouse video is arounded

Tags: flutter, video

Im using flutter_vlc_player to play rtsp video. however, the given video is like

[image]

the video rtsp streaming comes with fisheye effect in it and i have to remove the fisheye efftect.

i try to make shader but im unable to put it.

any idea? or any other way?

Comment: have u got any solution for it